# Pandas/Numpy Multiple if statement with and/or operators

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have quite a complex If statement that I would like to add as a column in my pandas dataframe. In the past I've always used numpy.select for this type of problem, however I wouldn't know how to achieve that with a multi-line if statement.

I was able to get this in Excel:

```
=IF(sum1=3,IF(AND(col1=col2,col2=col3),0,1),IF(sum1=2,IF(OR(col1=col2,col2=col3,col1=col3),0,1),IF(sum1=1,0,1)))
```

and write it in Python just as a regular multi-line 'if statement', just want to find out if there is a far cleaner way of presenting this.

```
if df['sum1'] == 3:
  if df['col1'] == df['col2'] and df['col2'] == df['col3']:
    df['verify_col'] = 0
  else:
    df['verify_col'] = 1
elif df['sum1'] == 2:
  if df['col1'] == df['col2'] or df['col2'] == df['col3'] or df['col1'] == df['col3']:
    df['verify_col'] = 0
  else:
    df['verify_col'] = 1
elif df['sum1'] == 1:
  df['verify_col'] = 0
else:
  df['verify_col'] = 1
```

Here's some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['BMW', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Lamborghini', 'Ferrari', null],
    'col2': ['BMW', 'Mercedes Benz', null, null, 'Tesla'],
    'col3': ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Lamborghini', null, 'Tesla_'],
    'sum1': [3, 3, 2, 1, 2]
})
```

I want a column which has the following results:

```
'verify_col': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

It basically checks whether the columns match for those that have values in them and assigns a 1 or a 0 for each row. 1 meaning they are different, 0 meaning zero difference.

Comment: I would be tempted to use `.apply` for this.  Are you familiar with that?  It calls a function that you provide on every row, and the result can be assigned to a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chain mask with `|` for bitwise `OR` - if no match any conditions is created `1`:

```
m1 = (df['sum1'] == 3)
m2 = (df['col1'] == df['col2']) & (df['col2'] == df['col3'])
m3 = (df['sum1'] == 2)
m4 = (df['col1'] == df['col2']) | (df['col2'] == df['col3']) | (df['col1'] == df['col3'])
m5 = df['sum1'] == 1

df['verify_col'] = np.where((m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4) | m5, 0, 1)
```

If need `None` if no match any conditions:

```
df['verify_col'] = np.select([(m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4) | m5,
                              (m1 & ~m2) | (m3 & ~m4) | ~m5], 
                             [0,1], default=None)


print (df)
            col1           col2         col3  sum1  verify_col
0            BMW            BMW          BMW     3           0
1  Mercedes Benz  Mercedes Benz     Mercedes     3           1
2    Lamborghini            NaN  Lamborghini     2           0
3        Ferrari            NaN          NaN     1           0
4            NaN          Tesla       Tesla_     2           1
```

Comment: @DeepakTripathi - I have typo, now correct

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.case_when(
# condition, result
df.sum1.eq(3) & df.col1.eq(df.col2) & df.col2.eq(df.col3), 0,
df.sum1.eq(3), 1,
df.sum1.eq(2) & (df.col1.eq(df.col2) | df.col2.eq(df.col3) | df.col1.eq(df.col3)), 0,
df.sum1.eq(2), 1,
df.sum1.eq(1), 0,
1, # default
column_name='verify_col')
)

            col1           col2         col3  sum1  verify_col
0            BMW            BMW          BMW     3           0
1  Mercedes Benz  Mercedes Benz     Mercedes     3           1
2    Lamborghini           None  Lamborghini     2           0
3        Ferrari           None         None     1           0
4           None          Tesla       Tesla_     2           1
```

Of course, you can do this with `np.select`:

```py
conditions = [df.sum1.eq(3) & df.col1.eq(df.col2) & df.col2.eq(df.col3), 
              df.sum1.eq(3), 
              df.sum1.eq(2) & (df.col1.eq(df.col2) | df.col2.eq(df.col3) | 
              df.col1.eq(df.col3)), 
              df.sum1.eq(2), 
              df.sum1.eq(1)]

results = [0,1,0,1,0]

outcome = np.select(conditions, results, default=1)
df.assign(verify_col = outcome)

            col1           col2         col3  sum1  verify_col
0            BMW            BMW          BMW     3           0
1  Mercedes Benz  Mercedes Benz     Mercedes     3           1
2    Lamborghini           None  Lamborghini     2           0
3        Ferrari           None         None     1           0
4           None          Tesla       Tesla_     2           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['verify_col'] = (~(((df["col1"] == df["col2"]) | df["col1"].isna() | df["col2"].isna()) & ((df["col2"] == df["col3"]) | df["col2"].isna() | df["col3"].isna()))).astype(int)
```